# upgrade TLS 1.2 and HTTP/1.1 for PayPal

Tags: paypal

PayPal sent a messege regarding security updates..
I've looked it up and there is a lot of information about these upgrades. example: http://www.paidmembershipspro.com/paypals-tls-1-2-http1-1-upgrade-impact-membership-site/

However it is unclear what exactly should be upgraded?
If my site has a shopping cart with PayPal check out - Do I need this upgrade?